# No such file or directory - assets in LocomotiveCMS Wagon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, liquid-layout, locomotivecms

Getting the `No such file or directory - /var/tmp/dragonfly.log` error message when trying to access assets from the `Public` folder. I am running Wagon on Win 8.1, Ruby v2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32], Rails 4.1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up "giving in" and installing the [Bitnami Ruby Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby). Sure enough, it worked. For those of us who know what its like to get Ruby to work properly on a Win machine, make sure you back up your original installation:

1. Copy the Ruby installation folder to a another location on my hard drive
2. Create a System Restore point to back up the registry
3. When installing the Bitnami Stack, uncheck `MySQL` and `Postgres`  (unless this is your first time installing them).

Bitnami will run in its own environment, but I have decided to play it safe and make sure I have a working copy of Ruby and gems to go back to.